# Powershell: Grant-NfsSharePermission Full Permissions

Tags: powershell, client-server, nfs, invalid-argument

Powershell v3.0                Windows Server 2012

I am trying to use the Grant-NfsSharePermission cmdlet to grant read/write access to all users with local admins having full permissions to a NFS share.

```
Grant-NfsSharePermission -Name "LABS" -Path "C:\LABS" -ClientName "WIN-TGE0C741D5G" -ClientType "builtin" -Permission readwrite
```

The error I get is the parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified name parameters. It's in the InvalidArgument category. After looking at the built-in examples, I can't seem to see why this is a problem. I even tried replacing the clientname (which is my machine name) with localhost and 127.0.0.1 and same error.

Comment: Is it a typo or do you actually have a space between the dash and 'Name' as shown: `Grant-NfsSharePermission - Name`

Comment: Ok if I take the -Path parameter it works but according to Syntax, the Path parameter is a valid parameter for this cmdlet so what gives?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It is a typo. I was c/p from a VM.

Comment: Run `Get-Help Grant-NfsSharePermission`, and you will see that there is two parameter sets for that cmdlet, and you cannot use both `-Name` and `-Path` in the same syntax.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Grant-NfsSharePermission cmdlet expects either the name of the NFS share or the path to the share. You provided both and it doesn't like that. Provide either just -Name or just -Path, but not both and it should work.

As TheMadTechnician mentioned in the comments, you can see this by reviewing the online help or built-in help (with Get-Help Grant-NfsSharePermission) and seeing they provide two parameter sets and the examples only show the use of one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for that. On another note, I didn't really see an "access" parameter for this cmdlet. The one for SmbShare does have an access parameter though so why do NFS cmdlets not have this feature? I only saw permissions.

Comment: Are you asking what the difference is between -AccessRight as part of Grant-SmbShareAccess and -Permission as part of Grant-NfsSharePermission?

Comment: Yes I am. I also realized for my particular task, I need to be using Smb shares not NFS shares. They look so similar for those who are unfamiliar to building file shares.

Comment: I can't say for sure why they used different terminology when creating the cmdlets but with both you are essentially setting the 'permissions' or 'access rights' for the share. For an SMB share that means setting ACLs which are based on users or groups and the access level they are allowed. For an NFS export/share you are setting the permission level for a client (or group of clients) based on IP, hostname, subnet, etc.

Comment: In PS7, is this no longer available?  or does it need to be installed?  I get "Grant-NfsSharePermission: The term 'Grant-NfsSharePermission' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."